image not found in Experiment Builder
I'm using Experiment Builder to code an eye-tracking experiment, where I keep running into this error where the experiment terminates itself right after the first trial. It would report the error "File does not exist: runtime/images/6785105752414573539.png". However, after looking at the imagelst file auto-generated by Experiment Builder, it's not even the corresponding image number of the actual first trial. I thought this was really weird and spent forever debugging, but haven't made any progress yet.
Things I've tried:
-Running a different list
-Cleaning and test running
-Changing column names
Would appreciate any suggestion and help! Thanks a lot!
